# Get Vim to automatically close when there are no more file buffers

Tags: vim

If I open vim to edit multiple files using an invocation such as `vim file1 file2 file3` and then proceed to edit each file and close the buffer using `:bd` I am left with an empty buffer once I have closed all the file buffers.

How would I change the behaviour so that when I close the last file buffer (with `:bd`), instead of dropping me into an empty buffer, Vim quits instead. Similar to `nano`s behaviour when editing multiple files and using `Ctrl+X` to close a buffer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should achieve what you're asking for. It iterates over all potential buffers and checks whether there are any buffers still listed or empty. The check is triggered whenever a buffer is deleted.

```
:autocmd BufDelete * if len(filter(range(1, bufnr('$')), '!empty(bufname(v:val)) && buflisted(v:val)')) == 1 | quit | endif
```

Answer (score 0):

```
How would I change the behaviour so that when I close the last file buffer, 
instead of dropping me into an empty buffer, Vim quits instead.
```

After your last edit, end with `:wqa`

If that isn't the behavior you are looking for perhaps you are looking for [**bbye**](https://github.com/moll/vim-bbye)

Comment: If there are a large amount of buffers and I don't know if I am on the last one or not, it would be nice to have the behaviour I mentioned above.

Comment: Add an `a` at the end: `:wqa`

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.

Comment: If you are editing the last buffer, of many, opened with `vim file1 file2 file3` are you saying `:wq` does not quit?

Comment: The point is that if I don't know if the buffer I am on is the last one or not, I'm not going to know to use `wq` or `wqa`. I would like a command I can use in either situation to accomplish the result I want. Hence why I'm asking how to modify the behaviour of `:bd`.

Comment: Now I understand what it is you want to do. I thought your already closed all buffers and were not liking the fact that vim remained running. `:bd` or `:bdelete` does exactly as you describe - closes all windows currently showing in the buffer. Thus if you were on the last one, a `:wq` would quit. Understanding now, that you may have not know you are on the final buffer, I don't know of a `vimrc` setting that would give you that behavior. However, there are many add-ons at the vim site that may accomplish this. Take a look at **http://vim.wikia.com**. Sorry for the confusion.